# Vega-Lite - How to plot stacked bar with labels in each nar?

Tags: plot, text, label, data-visualization, vega-lite

Given a stacked bar plot, how can I add labels with the values of each of the bar?

Below is an example of what I'm trying to do:
[image: Stacked bar example]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this by layering a bar mark and a text mark. For example ([open in editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJghgLhIFygK4CcA29zQgegEYTQFMBPAOgCsBnAewDsQBfAGhAHcBLMKAC3gBYADAJaFaAY2ph2tAObxQAD3kgoxAA6EMAR0QRaUdjAMA3TSwgyZyQjOia4ISogC2IFgDN2hVGAzEvPm6OMGIA1hgAXoTI1IwsxMqqGhi01M7SEOgeAb4OxgReqozMIKgQxNHwANqgzgThDvjIQaISUrLKEqjUzQgq6vYgqem0mUGe3rmOhpoMc0y19YkDGFCEClBBXT0YrNwzQWBKcAC0AIwArCxgCXAAzCWtktJyfWCEMOzofUmDwxlZEATQIOSgHEprDbLZIOHR6AxGdimIIWKw2OwYJyubKTPw5cY9OqbBykM7uYoMAC6DCAA)):

```json
{
  "data": {"url": "data/barley.json"},
  "width": 400,
  "encoding": {
    "x": {
      "type": "quantitative",
      "aggregate": "sum",
      "field": "yield",
      "stack": "zero"
    },
    "y": {"type": "nominal", "field": "variety"}
  },
  "layer": [
    {
      "mark": "bar",
      "encoding": {"color": {"type": "nominal", "field": "site"}}
    },
    {
      "mark": {"type": "text", "color": "white", "dx": -15, "dy": 3},
      "encoding": {
        "detail": {"type": "nominal", "field": "site"},
        "text": {
          "type": "quantitative",
          "aggregate": "sum",
          "field": "yield",
          "format": ".1f"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

[image]